# ROS Docker container on Windows experiencing significant delay in response

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows

I'm tryied to set up a ROS environment on Windows by creating a Docker container with Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic. I've utilized Docker Desktop with `network=host` to be able to use my host PC's network. I set up vscode to deploy the docker container using is [vscode ros2 workspace](https://github.com/athackst/vscode_ros2_workspace) template but changed the docker image to [melodic-full](https://hub.docker.com/layers/althack/ros/melodic-full/images/sha256-1daf54f986ab5405c5654de5c29ddf42510f5d2c21b6bafadf65d8a20efbe8c4?context=explore). I then set up a workspace and was able to successfully publish and subscribe to topics on a remote robot.

However, I'm encountering a persistent issue with a considerable 10-second delay before receiving responses. For instance, when I run `rostopic list`, it takes 10 seconds to display the list. Similarly, with `rostopic echo` there's a 10-second delay before anything is shown, but once subscribed, messages are updated in real-time. The same thing happens when trying to publish to a topic.

I've experimented with the Docker container on multiple Windows PCs and connected to various remote ROS core systems, but the delay persists across all scenarios.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this delay issue would be greatly appreciated. I would very much like to be able to develop on Windows and quite like the idea of using Docker, but with this delay issues it's completely unusable at the moment.